# with memoir, user-defined `\pagewidth` is always equal to stock width

Tags: xetex, memoir, texlive

I have some xelatex code that used to work a previous system, but no longer works on a new installation (KDE Neon (Ubuntu 20.04), tex-live 2021, ghostscript 9.54).

I use memoir to set trim marks of 5 mm. The type block is 140 by 140 mm, but when I create a `pspicture` of 140 by 140 mm, it seems to actually create a canvas of 150 by 150 mm, so corresponding to the whole stock size. In the following example, the numbers 1,2,...,9 are supposed to be placed at the edges and centres of the type block, but they are placed too far apart (corresponding to the extra width of the trim marks).

```
\documentclass[9pt,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\pagewidth}
\setlength{\pagewidth}{140mm}
\newlength{\trimwidth}
\setlength{\trimwidth}{5mm}

\trimLmarks
\setstocksize{\pagewidth + 2\trimwidth}{\pagewidth + 2\trimwidth}
\settrimmedsize{\pagewidth}{\pagewidth}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{\trimwidth}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\trimwidth}
\settypeblocksize{\pagewidth}{\pagewidth}{*}
\setlrmargins{0mm}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{0mm}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{0mm}{0mm}
\setheaderspaces{*}{0mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]

\usepackage{pstricks}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\psset{unit=1mm}
\begin{pspicture}(0, 0)(\pagewidth,\pagewidth)

\rput[B](0, \pagewidth){1}
\rput[B](.5\pagewidth, \pagewidth){2}
\rput[B](\pagewidth, \pagewidth){3}
\rput[B](0, .5\pagewidth){4}
\rput[B](.5\pagewidth, .5\pagewidth){5}
\rput[B](\pagewidth, .5\pagewidth){6}
\rput[B](0, 0){7}
\rput[B](.5\pagewidth, 0){8}
\rput[B](\pagewidth, 0){9}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I don't see anything in particular in the output or the log that seems relevant:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xelatex 2021.4.12)  17 APR 2021 16:02
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**me.tex
(./me.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2021/03/23 v3.7o configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
\onelineskip=\skip47
\lxvchars=\skip48
\xlvchars=\skip49
\@memcnta=\count175
\c@@memmarkcntra=\count176
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
\stockheight=\skip50
\stockwidth=\skip51
\trimtop=\skip52
\trimedge=\skip53

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem9.clo
File: mem9.clo 2008/01/30 v0.4 memoir class 9pt size option
)
\binding=\skip54
\spinemargin=\skip55
\foremargin=\skip56
\uppermargin=\skip57
\lowermargin=\skip58
\headdrop=\skip59
\normalrulethickness=\skip60
\mem@maxheadheight=\skip61
\mem@maxfootheight=\skip62
\headwidth=\skip63
\c@storedpagenumber=\count177
\memPD=\dimen138
\m@mabparskip=\skip64
\thanksmarkwidth=\skip65
\thanksmarksep=\skip66
\droptitle=\skip67
\c@book=\count178
\c@part=\count179
\c@chapter=\count180
\c@section=\count181
\c@subsection=\count182
\c@subsubsection=\count183
\c@paragraph=\count184
\c@subparagraph=\count185
\beforechapskip=\skip68
\midchapskip=\skip69
\afterchapskip=\skip70
\chapindent=\skip71
\bottomsectionskip=\skip72
\secindent=\skip73
\beforesecskip=\skip74
\aftersecskip=\skip75
\subsecindent=\skip76
\beforesubsecskip=\skip77
\aftersubsecskip=\skip78
\subsubsecindent=\skip79
\beforesubsubsecskip=\skip80
\aftersubsubsecskip=\skip81
\paraindent=\skip82
\beforeparaskip=\skip83
\afterparaskip=\skip84
\subparaindent=\skip85
\beforesubparaskip=\skip86
\aftersubparaskip=\skip87
\pfbreakskip=\skip88
\c@@ppsavesec=\count186
\c@@ppsaveapp=\count187
\ragrparindent=\dimen139
\everylistparindent=\dimen140
\parsepi=\skip89
\topsepi=\skip90
\itemsepi=\skip91
\parsepii=\skip92
\topsepii=\skip93
\topsepiii=\skip94
\itemsepii=\skip95
\itemsepiii=\skip96
\partopsepii=\skip97
\partopsepiii=\skip98
\m@msavetopsep=\skip99
\m@msavepartopsep=\skip100
\@enLab=\toks15
\abstitleskip=\skip101
\absleftindent=\skip102
\abs@leftindent=\dimen141
\absrightindent=\skip103
\absparindent=\skip104
\absparsep=\skip105
\c@vslineno=\count188
\c@poemline=\count189
\c@modulo@vs=\count190
\c@memfvsline=\count191
\vleftskip=\skip106
\vrightskip=\skip107
\stanzaskip=\skip108
\versewidth=\skip109
\vgap=\skip110
\vindent=\skip111
\vleftmargin=\dimen142
\c@verse=\count192
\c@chrsinstr=\count193
\beforepoemtitleskip=\skip112
\afterpoemtitleskip=\skip113
\c@poem=\count194
\beforePoemTitleskip=\skip114
\midPoemTitleskip=\skip115
\afterPoemTitleskip=\skip116

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2020/10/01 v2.5c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen143
\ar@mcellbox=\box47
\extrarowheight=\dimen144
\NC@list=\toks16
\extratabsurround=\skip117
\backup@length=\skip118
\ar@cellbox=\box48
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/dcolumn.sty
Package: dcolumn 2014/10/28 v1.06 decimal alignment package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/delarray.sty
Package: delarray 2014/10/28 v1.01 array delimiter package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
Package: tabularx 2020/01/15 v2.11c `tabularx' package (DPC)
\TX@col@width=\dimen145
\TX@old@table=\dimen146
\TX@old@col=\dimen147
\TX@target=\dimen148
\TX@delta=\dimen149
\TX@cols=\count195
\TX@ftn=\toks17
)
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen150
\lightrulewidth=\dimen151
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen152
\belowrulesep=\dimen153
\belowbottomsep=\dimen154
\aboverulesep=\dimen155
\abovetopsep=\dimen156
\cmidrulesep=\dimen157
\cmidrulekern=\dimen158
\defaultaddspace=\dimen159
\@cmidla=\count196
\@cmidlb=\count197
\@aboverulesep=\dimen160
\@belowrulesep=\dimen161
\@thisruleclass=\count198
\@lastruleclass=\count199
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen162
\ctableftskip=\skip119
\ctabrightskip=\skip120
\abovecolumnspenalty=\count266
\@linestogo=\count267
\@cellstogo=\count268
\@cellsincolumn=\count269
\crtok=\toks18
\@mincolumnwidth=\dimen163
\c@newflo@tctr=\count270
\mem@margin@floatbox=\box49
\@contcwidth=\skip121
\@contindw=\skip122
\abovecaptionskip=\skip123
\belowcaptionskip=\skip124
\subfloattopskip=\skip125
\subfloatcapskip=\skip126
\subfloatcaptopadj=\skip127
\subfloatbottomskip=\skip128
\subfloatlabelskip=\skip129
\subfloatcapmargin=\dimen164
\c@@contsubnum=\count271
\m@mscap@capbox=\box50
\m@mscap@fbox=\box51
\sidecapsep=\dimen165
\sidecapwidth=\dimen166
\m@m@tempdima=\dimen167
\m@mscapraise=\dimen168
\sidecapraise=\dimen169
\m@mscapmainwidth=\dimen170
\m@mscaplkern=\dimen171
\beforeepigraphskip=\skip130
\afterepigraphskip=\skip131
\epigraphwidth=\skip132
\epigraphrule=\skip133
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 7650.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 7658.
\tocentryskip=\skip134
\tocbaseline=\skip135
\cftparskip=\skip136
\cftbeforebookskip=\skip137
\cftbookindent=\dimen172
\cftbooknumwidth=\dimen173
\cftbeforepartskip=\skip138
\cftpartindent=\skip139
\cftpartnumwidth=\skip140
\cftbeforechapterskip=\skip141
\cftchapterindent=\skip142
\cftchapternumwidth=\skip143
\cftbeforesectionskip=\skip144
\cftsectionindent=\skip145
\cftsectionnumwidth=\skip146
\cftbeforesubsectionskip=\skip147
\cftsubsectionindent=\skip148
\cftsubsectionnumwidth=\skip149
\cftbeforesubsubsectionskip=\skip150
\cftsubsubsectionindent=\skip151
\cftsubsubsectionnumwidth=\skip152
\cftbeforeparagraphskip=\skip153
\cftparagraphindent=\skip154
\cftparagraphnumwidth=\skip155
\cftbeforesubparagraphskip=\skip156
\cftsubparagraphindent=\skip157
\cftsubparagraphnumwidth=\skip158
\prechapterprecisshift=\dimen174
\c@maxsecnumdepth=\count272
\bibindent=\dimen175
\bibitemsep=\skip159
\indexcolsep=\skip160
\indexrule=\skip161
\indexmarkstyle=\toks19
\@indexbox=\insert252
\glossarycolsep=\dimen176
\glossaryrule=\dimen177
\sideparvshift=\skip162
\sideins=\insert251
\sidebartopsep=\skip163
\sidebarhsep=\skip164
\sidebarvsep=\skip165
\sidebarwidth=\skip166
\footmarkwidth=\skip167
\footmarksep=\skip168
\footparindent=\skip169
\footinsdim=\skip170
\footinsv@r=\insert250
\@mpfootinsv@r=\insert249
\m@m@k=\count273
\m@m@h=\dimen178
\m@mipn@skip=\skip171
\sidefootins=\insert248
\sidefootadjust=\skip172
\sidefootheight=\skip173
\sidefoothsep=\skip174
\sidefootvsep=\skip175
\sidefootwidth=\skip176
\m@mdownsf=\skip177
\c@sidefootnote=\count274
\sidefootmarkwidth=\skip178
\sidefootmarksep=\skip179
\sidefootparindent=\skip180
\c@pagenote=\count275
\c@pagenoteshadow=\count276
\mem@pn@lastkern=\skip181
\every@verbatim=\toks20
\afterevery@verbatim=\toks21
\verbatim@line=\toks22
\tab@position=\count277
\verbatim@in@stream=\read2
\verbatimindent=\skip182
\verbatim@out=\write3
\bvboxsep=\skip183
\c@memfbvline=\count278
\c@bvlinectr=\count279
\bvnumlength=\skip184
\fb@frw=\dimen179
\fb@frh=\dimen180
\FrameRule=\dimen181
\FrameSep=\dimen182
\c@cp@cntr=\count280
\c@ism@mctr=\count281
\c@xsm@mctr=\count282
\c@csm@mctr=\count283
\c@ksm@mctr=\count284
\c@xksm@mctr=\count285
\c@cksm@mctr=\count286
\c@msm@mctr=\count287
\c@xmsm@mctr=\count288
\c@cmsm@mctr=\count289
\c@bsm@mctr=\count290
\c@workm@mctr=\count291
\c@sheetsequence=\count292
\c@lastsheet=\count293
\c@lastpage=\count294

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
)
\c@figure=\count295
\c@lofdepth=\count296
\cftbeforefigureskip=\skip185
\cftfigureindent=\skip186
\cftfigurenumwidth=\skip187
\c@table=\count297
\c@lotdepth=\count298
\cftbeforetableskip=\skip188
\cfttableindent=\skip189
\cfttablenumwidth=\skip190
Package abstract [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package appendix [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package booktabs [2016/05/16] emulated by memoir.
Package ccaption [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package changepage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngcntr [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package chngpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package crop emulated by memoir.
Package enumerate [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package epigraph [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package ifmtarg [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package index [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package makeidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package moreverb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package needspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package newfile [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package nextpage [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package pagenote [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package parskip [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package patchcmd [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package setspace [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package shortvrb [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package showidx [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titleref [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package titling [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocbibind [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocloft [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package tocvsec2 [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verbatim [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
Package verse [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count299
\calc@Bcount=\count300
\calc@Adimen=\dimen183
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen184
\calc@Askip=\skip191
\calc@Bskip=\skip192
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count301
\calc@Cskip=\skip193
)
\pagewidth=\skip194
\trimwidth=\skip195


******************************************************
Stock height and width: 426.7913pt by 426.7913pt
Top and edge trims: 14.22636pt and 14.22636pt
Page height and width: 398.33858pt by 398.33858pt
Text height and width: 398.33858pt by 398pt
Spine and edge margins: 0pt and 0pt
Upper and lower margins: 0pt and 0pt
Headheight and headsep: 0pt and 0pt
Footskip: 0pt
Columnsep and columnseprule: 10pt and 0pt
Marginparsep and marginparwidth: 7pt and 1pt
Sidecapsep and sidecapwidth: 7pt and 144pt
Sidebarhsep and sidebarwidth: 7pt and 144pt
Sidebarvsep and sidebartopsep: 10pt and 0pt
Sidebarheight: 546.99997pt
Sidefoothsep and sidefootwidth: 7pt and 144pt
Sidefootvsep and sidefootheight: 10pt and 546.99997pt
******************************************************

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
Package: pstricks 2020/06/11 v0.70 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2021/03/18 v5.0k Graphics/color driver for xetex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks23
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks24

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count302
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count303
\pstFP@xia=\count304
\pstFP@xib=\count305
\pstFP@xfa=\count306
\pstFP@xfb=\count307
\pstFP@rega=\count308
\pstFP@regb=\count309
\pstFP@regs=\count310
\pstFP@times=\count311
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks25
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen185
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen186

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks26
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks27

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks28
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Loading pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex
\pgf@x=\dimen187
\pgf@xa=\dimen188
\pgf@xb=\dimen189
\pgf@xc=\dimen190
\pgf@y=\dimen191
\pgf@ya=\dimen192
\pgf@yb=\dimen193
\pgf@yc=\dimen194
\c@pgf@counta=\count312
\c@pgf@countb=\count313
\c@pgf@countc=\count314
\c@pgf@countd=\count315
\pgfutil@tempcnta=\count316
\pgfutil@tempcntb=\count317
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen195
\pgfmath@count=\count318
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks29
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks30
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks31
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count319
))
\pgffor@iter=\dimen196
\pgffor@skip=\dimen197
\pgffor@stack=\toks32
\pgffor@toks=\toks33
)
\psLoopIndex=\count320

`PSTricks' v3.01a  <2021/03/30> (tvz,hv)
\pst@dima=\dimen198
\pst@dimb=\dimen199
\pst@dimc=\dimen256
\pst@dimd=\dimen257
\pst@dimg=\dimen258
\pst@dimh=\dimen259
\pst@dimm=\dimen260
\pst@dimn=\dimen261
\pst@dimo=\dimen262
\pst@dimp=\dimen263
\pst@hbox=\box53
\pst@ibox=\box54
\pst@boxg=\box55
\pst@cnta=\count321
\pst@cntb=\count322
\pst@cntc=\count323
\pst@cntd=\count324
\pst@cntg=\count325
\pst@cnth=\count326
\pst@cntm=\count327
\pst@cntn=\count328
\pst@cnto=\count329
\pst@cntp=\count330
\@zero=\count331
\pst@toks=\toks34
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg))
\psunit=\dimen264
\psxunit=\dimen265
\psyunit=\dimen266
\pst@C@@rType=\count332
\pslinewidth=\dimen267
\psk@startLW=\dimen268
\psk@endLW=\dimen269
\pst@customdefs=\toks35
\pslinearc=\dimen270
\pst@symbolStep=\dimen271
\pst@symbolWidth=\dimen272
\pst@symbolLinewidth=\dimen273
\everypsbox=\toks36
\psframesep=\dimen274
\pslabelsep=\dimen275
\sh@wgridXunit=\dimen276
\sh@wgridYunit=\dimen277
\pst@shift=\dimen278
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
)))
File: pstricks.tex 2021/03/30 v3.01a `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv))
File: pst-fp.tex 2020/11/20 v0.06 `PST-fp' (hv)

>>> Loading XeTeX special macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks-xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2021-03-18 L3 backend support: XeTeX

(|extractbb --version)
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count333
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count334
\g__color_backend_stack_int=\count335
\g__graphics_track_int=\count336
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box56
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count337
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count338
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count339
) (./me.aux)
\openout1 = `me.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 2
6.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 26.

Overfull \hbox (28.7913pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 40--41
[][]
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 40--41

 []


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

 [1

]
Overfull \vbox (28.45273pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []


[2] [3] (./me.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11193 strings out of 476919
 192148 string characters out of 5821840
 516580 words of memory out of 5000000
 31125 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 403454 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 60i,13n,66p,383b,209s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on me.pdf (3 pages).
```

(If I run the code with latex, the resulting dvi is entirely blank.)

Comment: in tl2021 security has been tighten. You need to call xelatex with `--output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg"` to process such pstricks.

Comment: Thanks! That solves the error and the missing `psline`. However, the `rput` are still placed wonkily, so apparently that has a different cause.

Comment: Do you have a log of this? In recent memoir the trim marks are added via the shipout hooks and thus your image should not interfere with them. But then again I never use pstricks, I normally use tikz

Comment: @daleif I've added it to the question. It's really puzzling, pstricks seems to be confused about what distance 1mm is, but it's idea of distance should be independent of what memoir does.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have a look the next time I'm at a computer. Note that you should also be able to compile via latex+dvips+ps2pdf or lualatex

Comment: I think I have found the cause: `\pagewidth` seems to overwrite an internal variable with that name, when I change it to `\newpagewidth`, the problem goes away. I didn't expect this, because the code used to work on a previous installation.

Comment: @daleif do latex and lualatex require a similar option to the one mentioned by @ulrike-fischer? Because when I try to run the code (which now works with xelatex) with latex or lualatex, `rput` places everything on top of each other at (0,0), and psline errors (under lualatex) with i.a. `.! Undefined control sequence. \c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks _Not_Configured_For_This_Format`

Comment: Not that I know of. You might need to delete the aux before changing engine. Btw I'm not sure those calculations you're doing in setstocksize even works, that requires that setsength being used underneath which you don't know. Better to use `\dimexpr \pagewidth+2\trimwidth` which does not need calc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have been able to puzzle together how this went wrong.

`\pagewidth` is actually a luatex macro (not sure since when). In 2018 (v3.7g), a check was added to memoir's `\mem@fixpagelayout` macro (which is executed at `\begin{document}`) that sets `\pagewidth` to be equal to `\stockwidth`, but only if `\pagewidth` is already defined.

So this is not a case where a user macro accidentally overrides a package macro (hence no warning), but vice-versa!